# Can you modify global action fields accessibility by profile?

Tags: field-level-security, global-actions

Is it possible to make fields in a global quick action editable to some profiles and read-only to other profiles?

For Example, I want profile1 to have access to editing certain fields, but profile2 should not be able to edit them. However both profiles can view the global action and edit all other fields in it.

Comment: A creative way to achieve this might be: to create different record types, and then create a separate global action (with the appropriate fields) you'd like per record type. Assign the profiles to only have access to the record type of interest, and then the global action that will be available to them is only based on their record type.  NOTE: I would *not* recommend this approach though - creating record types just for this requirement is probably most definitely not worth it. I only post to show a potential way to look at this

Comment: That is an interesting approach, but does this mean there is currently no approach to achieve this result by directly setting field-level permissions to the global action fields per profile?

Comment: You can set field level security (FLS) settings per profile, but I don't think you can do it per specific global action.  Regular Page Layouts have the ability to double click a field on that edit page to mark them as Required or Read Only just on the UI level, but they don't have anything like that for global actions (as far as I know).  If the profile doesn't ever need edit rights on the field, I suggest editing the FLS on the profile level and see what happens on the global action itself :-)